# Arranging circles in data visualisation

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

For my data visualisation I need to arrange **various sized circles** into a compact area - rectangle or circle. (See [this](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/visualizations/count-of-job-positions-in-city-of-) and [this](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/visualizations/gas-3) example.)

In theory it is a two-dimensional-irregular-[cutting-stock-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) but I would like to avoid going that way. You can find similar visualisations all over the web and I doubt they use any rigorous math.

All I need is the circles to appear to be arranged in some orderly fashion (with approximately  same distance between them). There must be an easier way than cutting stock math. With some exaggeration I can even imagine how 2D physics engine could use gravity to make the circles fall into a container of desired shape.

I will be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve is called "circle packing". Finding optimal packing densities in various shapes does indeed require rigorous math. However I was able to find some relatively simple opensource examples of circular packing algorithms.

http://wonderfl.net/c/fNNF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42067/2D-Circle-Packing-algorithm-ported-to-C

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Everything I read about packing was about same sized circles, leading me towards bin packing problem and cutting stock problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout d3.js; see http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/pack.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for the best solution, but just any decent solution, the iterative/physics approach should work: Place all circles, and apply a pushing force to each pair of circles until they do not overlap any more, or your loop runs out. (You will not have a way to determine if the circles fit in your area, so make sure the routine terminates)

If you want the circles to stick together, then apply an attracting force to any pair of circles that do not overlap.

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem with this approach is that you will not fit them into given shape. Yo do not know how big will the square (rectangle) or circle be. You would have to have to change the shape after adding every new circle to your calculation. I need to generate the visualisations in real time and this might be an overkill.