# How do I create different size round images

Tags: html, css

trying to replicate this effect using css/scss , so far tried with scss by applying different width to the children object ,but nothing seem to be working

```
.box-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}   
.box-container .box1{
    width: 30%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no grid approach here that will work...not even flexbox. The 'circles' are not in obvious columns or rows...and those are the foundation of current layout methods. You need something like masonry.js ...except for circles not rectangles.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121126/arranging-circles-in-data-visualisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three ways to do the rounded images**:

**1**- an image with `border-radius: 50%;`

**2**- a container with `border-radius: 50%;` and an image as background

**3**- a container with `border-radius: 50%;` and an image inside

*To add text just use options #2 or #3 with text inside the div.*

```css
body {
  background: honeydew;  
}

#stripe {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 38%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

#pic {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid skyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#imgcontainer {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid crimson;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#pic2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<img id=pic src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg">

<div id=imgcontainer><p id=stripe>text</p></div>

<div id=container><img id=pic2 src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"><p id=stripe>text</p></div>
```

I had no success distributing the circles on a container with zero space among them using `display:flex` or `float:left`, so I did place them one by one using `position:absolute` inside a `position:relative` container (not a handy solution and have several limitations but it does works in some scenarios).

*ps: notice the fact I'm using `padding-bottom` instead of `height` to keep the circles' aspect ratio.*

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: honeydew;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 346px;
  position: relative;
}

.imgcontainer {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#a {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}

#b {
  top: 0;
  left: 29%;
  width: 16%;
  padding-bottom: 16%;  
}

#c {
  top: 0;
  left: 44.5%;
  width: 23%;
  padding-bottom: 23%;
}

#d {
  top: 0;
  left: 67%;
  width: 33%;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
}

#e {
  top: 54%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 24%;
  padding-bottom: 24%;
}

#f {
  top: 32.5%;
  left: 23%;
  width: 33%;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
}

#g {
  top: 39.5%;
  left: 55.5%;
  width: 15.5%;
  padding-bottom: 15.5%;  
}

#h {
  top: 57.9%;
  left: 65.4%;
  width: 23%;
  padding-bottom: 23%;  
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<div id=a class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=b class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=c class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=d class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=e class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=f class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=g class=imgcontainer></div>
<div id=h class=imgcontainer></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest a container with radius:50% and the desired background color, along with a transparent png image (like the guitar). that will allows you more color options for each image by just changing the container background color.

Comment: @Dutchie432 thanks for your comment; After I show the possibilities to build the circles on the beginning of the answer, the focus on the second part of the post was to strike the big challenge of this question (which is the space among the circles). Being honest I'm still not satisfied with the final result (using position:absolute) but I don't know if today (2016) there's any workaround for this.

Comment: Yup, I was just adding my 2 cents for OP to recreate the posted image's effect.